# How to setup Qt SDK for Symbian development on Windows

Tags: qt, symbian

I am new to Qt for Symbian development, kindly guide me that how to set the development environment for Symbian in Qt, I have downloaded the offline installer of Qt for Windows:

Is this enough for Symbian development or do i need some more to install?
And kindly guide me from where i can learn quickly and have comprehensive helping material.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, enough. Open QtCreator. Welcome page will contain a lot of examples and guidelines. Qt's documentation is the best I ever saw. So don't be lazy and read it(right inside QtCreator).